# Program not responding when installed

Tags: c#, database

I've written a little tool to run a large amount of queries against a database and, when running it from Visual Studio, the application works great. The progress bar progresses and everything goes considerably smooth.

When I install the program on my Windows 10 machine and run the queries, however, the form stops responding.

The code runs single threaded so my question is: Why does the form update the progress bar when running on Visual Studio and why does it not respond when installed?

I'm not really sure how to fix this as the code is the exact same on both instances. Did I configure the installer incorrectly?

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
{
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    progressBar.PerformStep();
}
```

I expected the program to behave the same whether running on Visual Studio or installed locally but it does not.

Comment: I can't answer the "why", but if you're performing a long running operation you really should do it on another thread.  The reason being that you're form will lock up (as you've seen).  I'm confused that it worked while debugging.

Comment: The reason I wanted it done single threaded was exactly so I could update the progress bar. I'm not sure I'd be able to keep track how many queries have already run against the database if I ran it on a separate thread. Is it possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just have some variable and increment it using `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: You're correct, you can only update the progress bar from the main thread. 
 `BackgroundWorker`s (although antiquated) have an event called `ProgressChanged` that will execute on the thread it's subscribed from.  So you can run your separate thread and update the main thread on occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query has to be run on a separate thread. BackgroundWorkers can be used to run it separately whilst still updating the main thread from time to time.